# How to check the 'kind_of?', to 'count' or run other methods inside the RSpec 'its' feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9, RSpec-rails 2 and FactoryGirl. I am trying to check the `kind_of?`, to `count`, ... items present in an array using\inside the RSpec `its` feature. That is, I would like to make something like the following:

```
subject do
  Factory(
    :user,
    :articles => 3.times.inject([]) { |articles,i|
                   articles << Factory(
                     :article,
                     :user_id => Factory(:user)
                   )
                 }
end

# Note the (wrong!) usage of 'first', 'count' methods
its(:articles) { first.should be_kind_of(Article) }
its(:articles) { count.should == 10 }
```

But, since I get errors, it seems not possible to make that in the (wrong!) way I made it in the above code. **Is there a way to do that** (to check the `kind_of?`, `count`, ...)**?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://rdoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/master/RSpec/Core/Subject/ClassMethods:its:

```
  describe Person do
    subject do
      Person.new.tap do |person|
        person.phone_numbers << "555-1212"
      end
    end

    its("phone_numbers.first") { should eq("555-1212") }
  end
```

so in your case:

```
its('articles.first') { should be_kind_of(Article) }
its('articles.count') { should == 10 }
```